# Algorithm for Shortest Path with a contraint, BFS or DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Question stated as follow:

> Given a map which has some obstacles in it. Given a starting point S
>   and ending point E, find the shortest path from S to E. Note you can
>   choose any(4) direction from S, but during the process, you can only
>   go straight from the previous direction, unless you hit an obstacle.

I am confused with this constraint, but during the process, you can only

> go straight from the previous direction, unless you hit an obstacle.

Does that mean straightforward BFS won't be able to solve this problem? Will a modified BFS or DFS be able to find a solution for this?

Claim: I am looking for a solution, just some hints or thoughts.

Comment: i think you can do this with bfs where the nodes are all possible hits with an obstacle where you can change direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a straightforward BFS can turn at any cell, while in this problem, you can turn only when you hit a wall.

The problem can still be solved by a BFS on a modified graph.  To simulate the constraint correctly, you can create auxiliary vertices from which you can move in only one direction.

Alternatively, you can build another new graph with weighted edges and use a more general shortest paths algorithm (Dijkstra or Ford-Bellman) on it.  Specifically, when you stand in a cell and choose a direction, draw an edge to the cell where you can again change direction.  The weight of that edge is just the length of the straight path between the two cells.

Comment: can you explain " when you stand in a cell and choose a direction, draw an edge to the cell where you can again change direction. The weight of that edge is just the length of the straight path between the two cells."

Comment: Sure. Suppose you stand at `(1, 1)` and move along vector `(1, 0)`, i.e. increasing your x-coordinate. Let there be a wall at `(1, 5)`, so you will gain control again at `(1, 4)`. Then, instead of a usual edge from `(1, 1)` to `(1, 2)` of weight 1, you draw an edge from `(1, 1)` to `(1, 4)` of weight 3 = 4 - 1. Does this example answer your question?